# Raspberry Pi Model A ethernet

Tags: ethernet

I've tried to connect my RPi on anyone internet hotspot, but haven't ethernet connection and it block me to install or update any application on my RPi.

Today i found it :

http://m.dealextreme.com/p/usb-2-0-to-rj45-100-1000mbps-ethernet-lan-network-adapter-white-160153

Can it fix my problems?

Comment: It does mention "support" for linux, which generally means it requires no special driver (as opposed to "we wrote a linux driver for it").  USB devices are often standardized, and this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_USB claims the linux kernel supports ethernet over USB.  I haven't tried it myself though, so I can't say for sure.  `modprobe usbnet` does show the module mentioned exists on my pi.

Comment: Consider a USB WiFi dongle instead.  They are more used and therefore better supported.  Be certain to get one that is known to work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://dx.com/p/usb-2-0-to-rj45-100-1000mbps-ethernet-lan-network-adapter-black-160154) website it will work under Linux.  However it is worth noting that these types of connections are not usually used for internet connectivity.  They're usually used to supplement the transferal of messages from one computer to another.  Think more like an old serial connection vs actual internet.  For the cost though it's worth trying to see if you could make it work.

Comment: I'll try with this, and see what make it or if will work fine.

Comment: Would you mind posting here when you figure out if it'll work or not?  I have a model B, but I'm curious to know for future reference.

Comment: Yes i'll do it.
But i think that will not be this weak or maybe not this month because probably i'll buy from dx.com and as you should know they take many days to ship.